# RavenDB on docker behind traefik

Tags: docker, ravendb, docker-swarm, traefik, ravendb4

I'm trying to install Secured `RavenDB` on `docker` swarm with `Traefik` as reserved proxy. But, it's none of successful.

I can make the installation work to the last page. But at state **Restart Server**, it doesn't work anymore. The page show up: **Internal Server Error**.

I have checked traefik rule and backend, but none of successful.

Anyone has been done this. Please help me. Thanks !!!